# How to control positioning of elements like the bootstrap grid in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am using angular material library in angular 5 web app, but I am trying very hard to find any clue about positioning the elements inside the webapp (like bootstrap grid for example)

For example, I found a [very useful guide for the angularjs material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment), however using the same classes/attributes in angular 5 material doesn't work ([like this example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhd3bz?file=app%2Fapp.component.html))

For example using:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-around center">
```

So for `layout-align="space-around center"`, it doesn't put space between the row elements as it does in [AngularJS](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment)

Can someone guide me about what I have missed here? if there is a similar guide for angular 5 material like this? or this is done using some other theme like flex-layout?